# Open resources about cosmetics and beauty/body products

Tags: data-request, products

We're currently creating an open database of cosmetics and beauty/body products, just like we did for OpenFoodFacts, and I was wondering whether you knew of resources that might be helpful, and liberally licensed.

Comment: What type of data? Information on chemicals, consumer reviews, pricing?

Comment: virtually anything we can find, although we'd like to focus on facts (eg not reviews).
Here's a random example of what we did for food: http://world.openfoodfacts.org/product/8410573100137/patatas-fritas-lisas-quot-marinas-quot-con-aceite-de-oliva

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you are looking for but any cosmetic containing sunscreen is in the Structured Product Label dataset at FDA (http://labels.fda.gov/), which is part of the openFDA effort (https://open.fda.gov/drug/label/).

Answer (score 1):

Status update: While keeping work on OpenBeautyFacts, we found:

- the UNII database of ingredients (Public Domain, produced by the US gov) that we got linked to Wikidata (yay).
- various glossaries and system with an unclear licence (Colour Index)
- various ressources by the European Union (COSING), some being usable (they're not as clear on licences as the US, but it's translations made for the EU, so open)
- Some similar projects but none with an open licence so far

Answer (score 1):

We are now publishing our own data at https://world.openbeautyfacts.org/data